# How to stop the jumping jack of text change in React

Tags: reactjs

How to smoothly transition from text to svg in react.
As soon as I click on next button shown in pic as ">" ,the text changes to svg.But there is some sort of jumping due to change in overall height.
How can I smoothly transition between two.

> Note: Unfortunately, I can't share the code as this is not a personal
>   project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height of the containing element to the heighest element. Therefore you need to place them in a row with a negative margin-right so that they overlay each other. Only the element that you make visible will be shown when you hide the other elements with visibility: hidden;

Here is an example:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.block__element');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  elements.forEach(element => {
    if(element.classList.contains('block__element--visible')) {
      element.classList.remove('block__element--visible');
    } else {
      element.classList.add('block__element--visible');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
}
.block__element {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
}
.block__element--visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__element block__element--visible">
    <div style="background: #f00">Content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__element">
    <div style="height: 200px; background: #0f0">Longer content 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Toggle between elements</button>
```

Comment: thanks, I still need to implement this in my code but any idea is helpful .

Comment: it worked. i had to use useref and made some changes but the idea was same as you mentioned. hence accepting this as answer.